# Postfix doesn't send mails to own domain

Tags: domain-name-system, email, postfix, smtp

I have a problem that my kopano / postfix on ubuntu 18.04 doesn’t send mails to my own domain.

My domain is for example: example.com

I try to send a mail from admin@example.com to admin2@example.com
there comes the following error:

```
Jun 21 13:25:32 exchange postfix/qmgr[13899]: C30943A15A3: from=<not- 
reply@example.com>, size=3784, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 21 13:25:32 exchange amavis[3249]: (03249-05) Passed CLEAN     {RelayedInbound}, [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:63079 [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] <not-    reply@example.com> -> <admin@example.com>, Queue-ID: 456423A142E, Message-ID:     <01ae01d40952$90194350$b04bc9f0$@example.com>, mail_id: zhlvJZ3aV8GE, Hits: 2.2,     size: 2952, queued_as: C30943A15A3, 1507 ms
Jun 21 13:25:32 exchange postfix/lmtp[16290]: connect to example.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx]:24: Connection refused
Jun 21 13:25:32 exchange postfix/lmtp[16290]: C30943A15A3: to=    <admin@example.com>, relay=none, delay=0.01,     delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to example.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:24: Connection refused)
Jun 21 13:25:33 exchange postfix/smtps/smtpd[14561]: disconnect from     unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] ehlo=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=6
```

here is the output of postconf -n

```
root@exchange:~# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
bounce_queue_lifetime = 10m
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 2
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
disable_vrfy_command = yes
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maximal_queue_lifetime = 10m
message_size_limit = 10240000
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = exchange.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = exchange.example.com
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_bind_address = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,         reject_unauth_destination, reject_non_fqdn_sender
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,     reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/mailcert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/mailcert.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = example.com
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-users.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp
```

here is the output of postconf -M

```
root@exchange:~# postconf -M
smtps      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -o     syslog_name=postfix/smtps -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes -o     smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no -o     smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o     smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o     smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o     milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
pickup     unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp -o     syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq      unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu     user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu     user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F     user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq.     user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R     user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user}     ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR     user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
smtp-amavis unix -       -       -       -       2       smtp -o     smtp_data_done_timeout=1200 -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes -o     disable_dns_lookups=yes -o max_use=20
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n   -       -       -       -       smtpd -o     content_filter= -o local_recipient_maps= -o relay_recipient_maps= -o     smtpd_restriction_classes= -o smtpd_delay_reject=no -o     smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject -o smtpd_helo_restrictions= -    o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o     smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject -o     smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining -o     smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions= -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8 -o     smtpd_error_sleep_time=0 -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001 -o     smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000 -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0 -o     smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0 -o     receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks
2003       inet  n       -       -       -       -       lmtp
```

Answer (score 2):

I find these errors quite clear:

```
connect to localhost[127.0.0.1]:2003: Connection refused
status=deferred (connect to localhost[127.0.0.1]:2003: Connection refused)
```

The corresponding line in your `main.cf`:

```
virtual_transport = lmtp:[localhost]:2003
```

> [`virtual_transport`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_transport) (default: `virtual`)
>
> The default mail delivery
>   transport and next-hop destination for final delivery to domains
>   listed with `$virtual_mailbox_domains`. This information can be
>   overruled with the `transport(5)` table.
>
> Specify a string of the form `transport:nexthop` where *transport* is the
>   name of a mail delivery transport defined in `master.cf`. The `:nexthop`
>   destination is optional; its syntax is documented in the manual page
>   of the corresponding delivery agent.

The default `lmtp` transport in `master.cf` is `lmtp unix - - y - - lmtp` i.e. using a UNIX socket instead of a TCP port. Default TCP port for LMTP is usually 24. If you haven't specifically configured your LMTP to listen on `localhost:2003`, that's the error.

We can't say for sure what you are trying to do, but possible solutions may include:

- adding `2003 inet n - - - - lmtp` to `master.cf` OR
- removing hostname and port i.e. `virtual_transport = lmtp` OR
- removing `virtual_transport = lmtp:[localhost]:2003` altogether i.e. using default.

Comment: That was not the solution. Same error.

Comment: That was your problem, you just weren't able to fix it based on this answer. In this case I'd recommend to ask another question with the modified configuration files instead of modifying the original question. Recommended details: a) error(s) from logs b) output of command `postconf -n` for modified `main.cf` settings and c) output of command `postconf -M` for `master.cf` d) desired state.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem that the new server doesnt have the correct MX and A Records in DNS? For the Moment the domain Records are at another server.

Comment: I updated the original question with the acutal state of postconf -n and postconf -M and error log.

Comment: My solutions were **alternatives**. Now, as the error is `:24: Connection refused`, you need `24 inet n - - - - lmtp` instead of `2003 inet n - - - - lmtp`, in order to make it listen on port `24`.